OAuth2 Flutter Login Redirect Fails After First Login or Logout Using flutter_web_auth_2
I’m implementing an OAuth2 authentication flow in my Flutter app using flutter_web_auth_2. The authentication works fine after the first login (when the browser already has an active session), but during the first login or after a logout, the OAuth2 provider doesn’t redirect back to my app’s callback URL (com.app.app://oauthredirect).
com.app.app is scheme, oauthredirect is a host.
AndroidManifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:label="app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth_2.CallbackActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth_2">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="com.app.app" android:host="oauthredirect" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.android.camera.CropImage" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

        <!-- Flutter Metadata -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

This is login functionality
 // Clear existing tokens
      await _clearExistingTokens();

      // Determine platform type
      final String? platformType = _getPlatformType();

      // Generate PKCE parameters
      final codeVerifier = _generateCodeVerifier();
      final codeChallenge = _generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);

      // OAuth2 Configuration
      final String clientId = 'ad6jnO5ZuqIbrSQEtF05xA67Fc0JW7JJ6vQNYzuW';
      final String redirectUri = 'com.app.app://oauthredirect';
      final List<String> scopes = ['openid'];

      // Perform authentication
      final result = await FlutterWebAuth2.authenticate(
          url: _constructAuthorizationUrl(
            clientId: clientId,
            redirectUri: redirectUri,
            codeChallenge: codeChallenge,
            scopes: scopes,
          ),
          callbackUrlScheme: "com.app.app",
          options: FlutterWebAuth2Options(
            preferEphemeral: true,
          ));

      // Extract authorization code
      final Uri uri = Uri.parse(result);
      final String? code = uri.queryParameters['code'];

      if (code == null) {
        throw Exception('Authorization code not found');
      }

      // Exchange authorization code for tokens
      final Map<String, dynamic> tokenResponse = await _exchangeCodeForTokens(
        code: code,
        clientId: clientId,
        redirectUri: redirectUri,
        codeVerifier: codeVerifier,
      );

      // Extract tokens
      final String? accessToken = tokenResponse['access_token'];
      final String? idToken = tokenResponse['id_token'];

      if (accessToken == null || idToken == null) {
        throw Exception('Failed to retrieve tokens');
      }

      // Store tokens securely
      await _storeTokens(accessToken, idToken);

These are the logs on the backend side. As you can see it doesn't send any request to token endpoint after authentication

"POST /login/?next=/api/oauth2/authorize/%3Fclient_id%3Dad6jnO5ZuqIbrSQEtF05xA67Fc0JW7JJ6vQNYzuW%26redirect_uri%3Dcom.app.app%253A%252F%252Foauthredirect%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%26code_challenge%3DNigW_Vlfoj5B0pi81a4Vp6OPt8g8QRn05TaOOCp5pi4%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26nonce%3D1732190076328 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[21/Nov/2024 11:54:42] "GET /api/oauth2/authorize/?client_id=ad6jnO5ZuqIbrSQEtF05xA67Fc0JW7JJ6vQNYzuW&redirect_uri=com.app.app%3A%2F%2Foauthredirect&response_type=code&scope=openid&code_challenge=NigW_Vlfoj5B0pi81a4Vp6OPt8g8QRn05TaOOCp5pi4&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=1732190076328 HTTP/1.1" 302 0

What can cause this problem? I've checked redirect uri a thousand times already and it seems correct so it can't be the problem. Additionally, I've tried to implement authentication with flutter_appauth still the same problem. Oauth2 provider is custom, not google, github etc.
